# Triple Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is: Find the volume of the region enclosed by $z=1-y^2$ and $z=y^2-1$ for $0\le x\le 2$.

Graphing it I find that it seems to be easiest to split it into four parts and find one of the parts volumes, then multiply by four. I chose the top right section and got the bounds: $0\le x\le 2$, $0\le y\le 1$, $0\le z\le 1-y^2$.

So the integral would be: $4\int_0^1\int_0^2\int_0^{1-y^2}?dzdxdy$.

I am not sure if this is correct or not, or if I need some function in the place of the question mark or if it is just: $1$.

Comment: Just $1$. Taking advantage of the symmetries is good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would doing dzdydx be easiest? So I only am dealing with one variable at a time...

Comment: @MathMano8 You can take the $dx$ out since the function you are integrating does not take values of $x$.  Since you're integrating from $0$ to $2$, $4 \int_0^2 C dx = 8 C$ (where $C$ represents the result you get after integrating with respect to $z$ and $y$).

Comment: For the question mark, the function that usually replaces that is the density of the region at a certain point (for instance, oxygen levels at different points in the room). When finding volume, the density is the same everywhere (the density is 1). As andrew suggested, you can separate the dx and everything else is fine!

Comment: As in the remark by Andrew Salmon, I would multiply by $2$ at the end instead of "integrating" with respect to $x$, since the solid has thickness $2$. But it makes no real difference, since the integration with respect to $x$ is trivial.

Comment: Okay, I got $16/3$ as my answer. Thanks guys.